# URLs in "Recent" list of DataSE are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

On dataSE, the "Recent" list under ones profile is broken; the ID component for all of the URLs are "0", resulting in a 404 for all URL's

- [Recent List](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6124/matt6125?order_by=recent)
- [Example URL - /stackoverflow/query/**0**/my-suggested-edit-votes-that-got-overruled](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/0/my-suggested-edit-votes-that-got-overruled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the query wasn't grabbing the `QuerySetId` when you were on that tab, so it stuck a zero in the URL instead. I'm not entirely sure if those URLs are meant to be query set or revision based, but assuming the former I've [patched the problem](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=2fcbfa238b472cce95b74a8255aa7f324bcaf605) by moving the line that selects that ID out into the common code.